# Start Android App by URL on NFC Tag

Tags: android, nfc

I was writing an URL to some NFC-Tag to intent-filter the hostname - start the app if installed or provide a link to google-play if the app is not installed. Unfortunately only the browser comes up:

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
 <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the action needs to be different:

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <data android:host="example.com" android:scheme="http" />
 </intent-filter>
```

still no permission needed